# MongoDB aggregate by multiplied sum of fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My original query looks like this:

```
{
  $group: {
     _id: "$seller",
     profit: { $sum: { $subtract: ["$revenue", "$expenses"] } }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to multiply that profit field by X, something like:

```
total: { 
   $multiply: [ 
      { $sum: { $subtract: ["$netReturn", "$totalStake"] } }, 
      10
   ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

Since multiplication is distributive over addition, you can rearrange that a little bit to multiple each term separately, and then sum them with the accumulator:

```
total: { 
   $sum:{
     $multiply: [ 
      {$subtract: ["$netReturn", "$totalStake"] }, 
      10
   ]} 
}
```